# Como fazer request com número inteiro?

Tags: java, html, servlet, glassfish

Eu tenho o seguinte form:

```
<form action="backend" method="get">
            <h1>Bem vindo ao Teacher Points</h1>
            <h3>Sistema web para calcular pontuação de Professores.</h3>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses no cargo:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_cargo"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses na lotação:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_lotacao"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses na carreira adjunto:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_adjunto"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses na carreira titular:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_titular"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magisterio: </tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="magisterio"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Calcular pontuação"/>
            </td>

            </table>
```

Ele está enviando os valores para meu Servlet chamado "backend", o problema é na hora de fazer o request, eu fiz o seguinte codigo:

```
int mes_cargo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mes_cargo"));
int mes_lotacao = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mes_lotacao"));
int mes_adjunto = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mes_adjunto"));
int mes_titular = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mes_titular"));
int magisterio = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mes_magisterio"));
```

porém quando envio pro Servlet ele me retorna um erro HTTP Status 500 com a seguinte mensagem

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
```

E eu nao sei o que fazer, provavelmente não estou fazendo o request direito e ta mandando null em todos os imputs

Comment: Onde o erro é acusado? Você está recebendo os valores no backend? O código está no mesmo endereço do form?

Comment: o erro é acusado logo após eu clicar no submit do html "Calcular pontuação"

Comment: eu recebo os valores com o request que comentei lá em cima, porém não sei se está correto

Comment: Estao no mesmo projeto porém em pastas diferentes, o meu servlet esta em "Teacher Points Web\src\java\br\com\teacherpoints\control" Ja o meu html esta no "Teacher Points Web\web"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema era que eu não estava fechando a tag  e tinha parametro escrito errado. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: se possível, complete a resposta com o código correto, isso pode auxiliar outras pessoas da comunidade.

Answer (score 2):

Olá @Arthur!

Esse erro acontece quando você está tentando converter um valor não numérico ou nulo para o tipo inteiro. Exemplo:

```
Integer.parseInt(null);
Integer.parseInt("a");
Integer.parseInt("");
Integer.parseInt(" ");
Integer.parseInt("1a");
```

Você precisa verificar os valores que estão sendo enviados para o seu servlet.

Comment: Ok, agora está começando a fazer sentido... Mas como faço essa verificação?

Comment: Você pode debugar cada `request.getParameter()` ou printar o seu resultado no console para ver o que está chegando no backend.

Por exemplo: `System.out.println(request.getParameter("mes_cargo"))`.

*Obs.: Se disse algo errado me corrijam por favor, só usei java na faculdade :)*

Comment: ta mas como eu faço pra transformar em inteiro?

Comment: ta chegando null no console

Comment: Precisa mostrar como está o seu Servlet.

Comment: quer q eu mande aqui meu servlet?

Answer (score 0):

No final meu index ficou assim

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teacher Points Web</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta author="Arthur dos Santos Almeida">
        <!--Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/arthursantosalmeida/-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/teacher.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="backend" method="get">
            <h1>Bem vindo ao Teacher Points</h1>
            <h3>Sistema web para calcular pontuação de Professores.</h3>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses no cargo:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_cargo"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses na lotação:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_lotacao"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses na carreira adjunto:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_adjunto"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meses na carreira titular:</tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="mes_titular"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magisterio: </tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="magisterio"/></tr>
            </tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Calcular pontuação"/>
            </td>

            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```